# Failed at the kurento-composite-call@6.1.1-dev start script

Tags: npm, kurento

I need some help about setting up group video chat using Kurento.
This is the error that I get when I try to connect the second person to the web application:

```
argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.41
npm ERR! npm v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! kurento-composite-call@6.1.1-dev start: node server.js
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the kurento-composite-call@6.1.1-dev start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the kurento-composite-call package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs kurento-composite-call
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls kurento-composite-call
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /home/goldsoft25/Desktop/NodeJS/kurento-tutorial-node-master/KurentoExample/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more info. Have you checked the log file that the message is pointing in the last line? Also, please use the latest version of the tutorials, or you'll have some issues that have been already solved.

Comment: ok ... let me check and see the log file.  i have the npm-debug.log which I have opened as an issue on github.